# Download file with node-downloader-helper

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, rest, node-modules

When I try to download a file and give it a unique name using node-downloader-helper I get the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ofek.bh\Desktop\Zoon2Drive\zoom-oauth-sample-app\video\TA - QA Apr 2020 - (Wed Jul 15 2020 15:02:08 GMT+0300 (שעון ישראל (קיץ))).mp4'
Emitted 'error' event on b instance at:
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ofek.bh\Desktop\Zoon2Drive\zoom-oauth-sample-app\node_modules\node-downloader-helper\dist\index.js:1:9035)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at internal/fs/streams.js:375:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:164:23) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\ofek.bh\\Desktop\\Zoon2Drive\\zoom-oauth-sample-app\\video\\TA - QA Apr 2020 - (Wed Jul 15 2020 15:02:08 GMT+0300 (שעון ישראל 
(קיץ))).mp4'
```

This is my code,
The error occurs when I add a value to `fileName`.
When `fileName` is empty, everything works fine.

```
const { DownloaderHelper } = require('node-downloader-helper');

function downloaderHelper (url, file_Name) {
    var filePath = `./video`
    var options = {
        method: 'GET', // Request Method Verb
        headers: {},  // Custom HTTP Header ex: Authorization, User-Agent
        fileName: `${file_Name}.mp4`,// Custom filename when saved
        retry: false, // { maxRetries: number, delay: number in ms } or false to disable (default)
        forceResume: false, // If the server does not return the "accept-ranges" header, can be force if it does support it
        removeOnStop: true, // remove the file when is stopped (default:true)
        removeOnFail: true, // remove the file when fail (default:true)
        // override: true,
        httpRequestOptions: {}, // Override the http request options  
        httpsRequestOptions: {}, // Override the https request options, ex: to add SSL Certs
    }

    const dl = new DownloaderHelper(url, __dirname+'/video/', options);
    
    dl.on('end', () => console.log('Download Completed'))
    dl.start();
}


exports.downloaderHelper = downloaderHelper;
```

My ultimate goal is to download a video file via URL, save the file in a dedicated folder and rename it.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to download from my local machine, I'm trying to save on the local machine. The `url` property Is an HTTP link.

Comment: Make sure the folder "video" exists before using it, also I noticed that the filename has some foreign character, probably trying to removing those?, what about if you just name the file "video.mp4" does it works?

Comment: Hi, The foreign characters are characters in the Hebrew language, the Date function gives these characters. In my opinion it has nothing to do with it because only when I just call a file named "video.mp4" for the purpose of the example, and do not insert its name through some variable then the program works.
I also did a test that really the variable is of the String type and indeed it is.

Comment: Even without the Date function, when the file name I want to give comes through some variable (which of course is a string type), it never works. Only when I give the name directly does it work.

Comment: so you mean that if put  in the options { ..., fileName: "video.mp4" }, it works? , if that the case, it seems there is an issue with the variable "file_Name",  probably some character not supported by windows, this seems to be an issue related with windows filesystem rather than the library, probably you could check this URL, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions